# parse xml and binding data to listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, xml-parsing

It's very simple task, but I struggle for hours.
I have parse xml from web sources and bind them to listbox. Now I want to make an index for each items binded to list box, something like this:

```
1.Title   2.Title   3.Title
  Author    Author    Author
  Date      Date      Date
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Name="stkPnl"  Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="15,0" MouseEnter="stkPnl_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="stkPnl_MouseLeave">
                        <Image x:Name="imageAV" Source="{Binding avlink}" Height="80" Width="80" 
                               Stretch="UniformToFill" MouseLeftButtonUp="imageAV_MouseLeftButtonUp" ImageFailed="imageAV_ImageFailed"/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,0,0,0" MouseLeftButtonUp="StackPanel_MouseLeftButtonUp">                                                               
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding nickname}" Width="Auto" />                               
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding track}" FontWeight="Bold" Width="Auto"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding artist}" Width="Auto"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

and MainPage.xaml.cs

```
        private void DoWebClient()
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://music.mobion.vn/api/v1/music/userstop?devid="));
        webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_OpenReadCompleted);

    }

    void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(e.Result))
        {

            string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Stream str = e.Result;
            str.Position = 0;
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(str);

            var data = from query in xdoc.Descendants("user")
                       select new mobion
                       {
                           avlink = (string)query.Element("user_info").Element("avlink"),
                           nickname = (string)query.Element("user_info").Element("nickname"),
                           track = (string)query.Element("track"),
                           artist = (string)query.Element("artist"),
                       };
            listBox.ItemsSource = data;
        }
    }
```

As you see I only have nickname, track and artist, if I want to add an index that increase for each listboxItem, how can I do that? 
Thank you for reading this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've an appropriate field in you `mobion` class (which you can bind to in the view), you can use an incrementing counter to populate this field as the document is iterated over.

```
int[] counter = { 1 };       

var data = from query in xdoc.Descendants("user")
           select new mobion
           {
               index = counter[0]++,
               avlink = (string)query.Element("user_info").Element("avlink"),
               nickname = (string)query.Element("user_info").Element("nickname"),
               track = (string)query.Element("track"),
               artist = (string)query.Element("artist"),
           };
```

Note that `counter` is an array of int rather than just an int to prevent accessing a modified closure.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's ugly, but it's an idea: Create a wrapper class for around your mobion class:

```
public class mobionWrapper : mobion
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
}
```

Instead of selecting mobion instances you select mobionWrapper instances:

```
var data = from query in xdoc.Descendants("user")
            select new mobionWrapper
            {
                avlink = (string)query.Element("user_info").Element("avlink"),
                nickname = (string)query.Element("user_info").Element("nickname"),
                track = (string)query.Element("track"),
                artist = (string)query.Element("artist"),
            };
```

After binding the your data, set the Index property of your wrapper class:

```
listBox.ItemsSource = data;

for(int i = 0; i < listBox.Items.Count; i++)
{
    var item = listBox.Items[i] as mobionWrapper;
    item.Index = i + 1;
}
```

Now you need a new TextBlock and bind it to the Index property:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}" Width="Auto" />
```

Worked for me. Keep in mind that the index might be invalid after sorting or filtering the data display.